# Angular после добавления элемента массива контроллера, вью не отрисовывается

Tags: javascript, angularjs

При добавлении нового объекта в массив, модель не отрисовывается. Данные добавляются через модальное окно.

Не понимаю, вроде двусторонний байндинг должен был сработать и отрисовать, однако нет. Представления не имею - что это может быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="myController">
            <h1>Задания</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#">Новые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">В работе</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">На рассмотрении</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Выполнены</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Отменены</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Черновики</a></li>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button onClick="getElementById('win').removeAttribute('style');" class="button" type="button">Добавить</button>
            <div id="win" style="display:none;">
                <div id="win">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="visible">
                        <h2>Добавить в таблицу</h2>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4>Присвоить ID</h4>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="itemId" type="text" placeholder="ID">
                            <h4>Какой город</h4>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="city" type="text" placeholder="Название города">
                            <h4>Необходимая услуга</h4>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Наименование услуги">
                            <h4>Срок</h4>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="complete" type="text" placeholder="Срок выполнения">
                            <h4>Стоимость</h4>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="price" type="text" placeholder="Стоимость">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" onClick="getElementById('win').style.display='none';">Отмена</button>
                         <button type="submit"  ng-click="createTask()">Добавить в таблицу</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по слову">
                <label><input type="checkbox"/>Персональное</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox"/>Ночное</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox"/>Срочное</label>

                <a href="#"> Никита Ласточкин</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Город</td>
                        <td>Название</td>
                        <td>Выполнить до</td>
                        <td>Сумма</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                        <td ng-bind = "task.itemId"></td>
                        <td ng-bind = "task.city"></td>
                        <td ng-bind = "task.name"></td>
                        <td ng-bind = "task.complete"></td>
                        <td ng-bind = "task.price"></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </section>
```

JS:

```
var tableController = angular.module("App", []);

tableController.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    console.log($scope);
$scope.tasks = [{
    itemId: 10256,
    city: "Самара",
    name: "Подключение провода от клеемной коробки пожарной сигнализации к расцепителю, проверить работоспособность",
    complete: "13 Августа",
    price: "10 201р"

    }, {
    itemId: 10256,
    city: "Самара",
    name: "Подключение провода от клеемной коробки пожарной сигнализации к расцепителю, проверить работоспособность",
    complete: "13 Августа",
    price: "10 201р"

    }
                 , {
    itemId: 10256,
    city: "Самара",
    name: "Подключение провода от клеемной коробки пожарной сигнализации к расцепителю, проверить работоспособность",
    complete: "13 Августа",
    price: "10 201р"

    }

]

    $scope.createTask = function () {
        $scope.tasks.push({itemId: $scope.itemId,
                           city: $scope.city,
                           name: $scope.name,
                           complete: $scope.complete,
                           price: $scope.price});
        console.log($scope.tasks);

    };

});
```

Comment: На вид все нормально и должно работать. Может, они добавляются, но не отображаются, например из-за стилей. Посмотрите во вкладке `Elements`, есть ли там элементы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы два раза используете контроллер `myController` для разных **HTML** элементов.
Соответственно у вас сейчас создается два экземпляра `myController`, которые никак не связаны между собой.

Вот работающий пример вашего кода.

```js
var tableController = angular.module("App", []);

tableController.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.tasks = [{
      itemId: 10256,
      city: "Самара",
      name: "Подключение провода от клеемной коробки пожарной сигнализации к расцепителю, проверить работоспособность",
      complete: "13 Августа",
      price: "10 201р"

    }, {
      itemId: 10256,
      city: "Самара",
      name: "Подключение провода от клеемной коробки пожарной сигнализации к расцепителю, проверить работоспособность",
      complete: "13 Августа",
      price: "10 201р"

    }, {
      itemId: 10256,
      city: "Самара",
      name: "Подключение провода от клеемной коробки пожарной сигнализации к расцепителю, проверить работоспособность",
      complete: "13 Августа",
      price: "10 201р"

    }

  ]

  $scope.createTask = function() {
    $scope.tasks.push({
      itemId: $scope.itemId,
      city: $scope.city,
      name: $scope.name,
      complete: $scope.complete,
      price: $scope.price
    });
    console.log($scope.tasks);

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <section>
      <h1>Задания</h1>
      <button onClick="getElementById('win').removeAttribute('style');" class="button" type="button">Добавить</button>
      <div id="win" style="display:none;">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="visible">
          <h2>Добавить в таблицу</h2>
          <div class="content">
            <h4>Присвоить ID</h4>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="itemId" type="text" placeholder="ID">
            <h4>Какой город</h4>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="city" type="text" placeholder="Название города">
            <h4>Необходимая услуга</h4>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Наименование услуги">
            <h4>Срок</h4>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="complete" type="text" placeholder="Срок выполнения">
            <h4>Стоимость</h4>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="price" type="text" placeholder="Стоимость">
          </div>
          <button type="button" onClick="getElementById('win').style.display='none';">Отмена</button>
          <button type="submit" ng-click="createTask()">Добавить в таблицу</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по слову">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Персональное</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Ночное</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>Срочное</label>

        <a href="#"> Никита Ласточкин</a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Город</td>
            <td>Название</td>
            <td>Выполнить до</td>
            <td>Сумма</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
            <td ng-bind="task.itemId"></td>
            <td ng-bind="task.city"></td>
            <td ng-bind="task.name"></td>
            <td ng-bind="task.complete"></td>
            <td ng-bind="task.price"></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```